# I can´t install pip after following all the tutorials and multiple wesites

Tags: python, pip

So, I have unstalled python 3.8 but when I check if pip is installed, it is not:

```
C:\Users\joaog>pip --version
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
C:\Users\joaog>py
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

And when I do theprocedures to install pip and run the line "python pip-get.py" nothing happens. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Try `py -m pip` or `pip3`.

Comment: 1) Don't ask it over again, look for previous similar questions. 2) It is useless to show the execution of the command *py* and then ask about problems with *python*

Answer (score 0):

as maciek97x said, try with **pip3** ... otherwise check your enviornment path.